# How to set customize date format in tizen native app

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to set minute and second in timer app. But when i use `FORMAT "%T"` it shows hour and minute. [image: Get this picture for the following format]

My code where i set the time and it shows by default `Hr & Min`

```
elm_datetime_format_set(datetime, FORMAT);
elm_object_style_set(datetime, "timepicker/circle");
elm_object_part_content_set(layout, "elm.swallow.content", datetime);
Elm_Datetime_Time dt;
dt.tm_hour = dt.tm_min = dt.tm_sec = 0;
elm_datetime_value_set(datetime, &dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/wearable/component-datetime

ELM_DATETIME_YEAR: Year field

ELM_DATETIME_MONTH: Month field

ELM_DATETIME_DATE: Date field

ELM_DATETIME_HOUR: Hour field

ELM_DATETIME_MINUTE: Minute field

ELM_DATETIME_AMPM: AM/PM field

As following development guide, the second is not available on datetime.

I guess you are working on tizen-stdio.
If so, the UiComponents will helps.

File->New->Tizen Project->Sample->Wearable->Native Application->UI->(Circle)UI Components->Finish

After create sample application you can see the sample for that in src->eext_spinner.c

```
minute = elm_spinner_add(layout);
elm_object_style_set(minute, "circle");
//Circle spinner add for circular visual interaction with rotary event.
eext_circle_object_spinner_add(minute, ad->circle_surface);
elm_spinner_min_max_set(minute, 0.0, 59.0);
elm_object_part_text_set(minute, "elm.text", "Minute");
evas_object_smart_callback_add(minute, "focused", _focused_cb, minute);
elm_object_part_content_set(layout, "minute", minute);

second = elm_spinner_add(layout);
elm_object_style_set(second, "circle");
//Circle spinner add for circular visual interaction with rotary event.
eext_circle_object_spinner_add(second, ad->circle_surface);
elm_spinner_min_max_set(second, 0.0, 59.0);
elm_object_part_text_set(second, "elm.text", "Second");
evas_object_smart_callback_add(second, "focused", _focused_cb, second);
elm_object_part_content_set(layout, "second", second);
```

There are three fields (Hour, Min, Sec) tho, you can refer that codes.